# How to use extension methods with fragment manager

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I am learing how to use extension menthods with fragmentmanager.
however, given the below code, i received a warning.

**Warning :**

> "use the getter method instead of property access"

Could anyone please give me tips on how to fix this?

```
private fun AppCompatActivity.getFragmentManagerInstance(): 
    FragmentManager? {
    return getSupportFragmentManager()//this error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the warning is actually suggesting to use getSupportFragmentManager() directly as getter method instead of doing above stuff.i hope you get it.thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Kotlin uses readable syntax(conventions) to access properties. For example instead of `textView.getText()` and `textView.setText(String)`, you can use `textView.text` to get a value and `textView.text = String` to set a value for text attribute of `TextView`. Also [see](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) So replace your code with:

```
private fun AppCompatActivity.getFragmentManagerInstance():
        FragmentManager? {
    return supportFragmentManager
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The IDE is suggesting to use `supportFragmentManager` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`, as it is the more idiomatic way in Kotlin.

More about it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters)